# Will Unity improve in 10.10, or do we have to wait till 11.04?

Tags: 10.10, unity, 11.04

I am currently running Unity on my Dell Mini 9 netbook. I like the interface, but it seems a bit less "baked" than the previous NBR shell.

For instance, performance is not great, it tends to be buggy, and it is overly difficult to manage the toolbar.

With the realization that Unity will become the defacto interface for 11.04, and much of the plumbing being reworked (i.e. porting to Compiz) - how much better will Unity be in 10.10?

Is there any hope of getting improvements in any of the areas above, or will I just have to wait until 11.04 to see any tangible improvements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think (as far as I know and how things have worked in the past) officially in the repositories you will only get security and important bug fix updates. You probably will not see any new code from Unity in 11.04 and beyond. Though there might be hope for a "semi-official" backport, as the 10.10 Unity has a PPA repository for 10.04. The same might be true for 11.04 -> 10.10. Time will tell.

Comment: I just hope that someone from the Unity team will create a backport for 10.10 even though they wont gain much from doing so. They have very less time and would prefer investing their time in porting rather than making it available for older releases

Answer (score 1):

Now, Unity is average WM. But, in my opinion, Canonical will improve their Unity all the time until 11.04. Although it will be minor improvements, Natty will have brand new Unity. Not Unity that we know. This WM will be Canonical's direction of work  for this 6 months. So, I'll recommend you to wait until Natty, where will be many changes and improvments about Unity.